# Html2pdf download pdf

Tags: html, html2pdf

I really don't know on how to solve this problem. I'm using html2pdf library to convery my html to pdf. Okay, so I have a download button wherein the user can download the html to pdf. But I got these errors: I've also checked the closing tags in html. Thanks guys.

Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\HtmlParsingException: Tags are closed in a wrong order for [div] in C:\xampp\htdocs\DTR\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Parsing\Html.php:262 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\DTR\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Parsing\Html.php(94): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Parsing\Html->getTagAction(Object(Spipu\Html2Pdf\Parsing\Token), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\DTR\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php(594): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Parsing\Html->parse(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\DTR\pages\download.php(18): Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf->writeHTML('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n...') #3 {main}

```
<page style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-one-half">
            <div class="top-left-text">
                <h4>CHRD - 001 - 0</h4>
                <h4>(Civil Service Form No. 48)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center-text">
                <h2>Daily Time Record</h2>
                <div class="line">-----o0o-----</div>
                <h4 class="name">Sample Name<h4>
                <h4 class="category">(Name)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center--info-text">
                <p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018<p>
                <p>Official hours for arrival &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Regular days Monday - Friday</p>
                <p>and departure 8 AM - 5 PM &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Saturdays None</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table-dtr">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Day</th>
                        <th colspan="2">A.M.</th>
                        <th colspan="2">P.M.</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Undertime</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <th>Departure</th>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <th>Departure</th> 
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th>Minutes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>16</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>17</th>
                        <td>07:35 AM</td>
                        <td>12:01 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>18</th>
                        <td>07:58 AM</td>
                        <td>12:07 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>19</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>20</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>21</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>22</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>23</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>24</th>
                        <td>08:05 AM</td>
                        <td>12:04 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>25</th>
                        <td>07:37 AM</td>
                        <td>12:05 PM</td>
                        <td>12:50 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>26</th>
                        <td>07:50 AM</td>
                        <td>12:05 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:02 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>27</th>
                        <td>07:31 AM</td>
                        <td>12:00 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>28</th>
                        <td>07:26 AM</td>
                        <td>12:06 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>29</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>30</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">Total</th>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text-center--info-text t-bottom">
                    <p> I certify on my honor that the above is a true and correct report of the hours of work performed, record of which was made daily at the time of arrival and departure from office.</p>
                </div>
                <p class="underline">___________________________________________</p>
                <p>VERIFIED as to the prescribed office hours:</p>
                <p class="underline">___________________________________________</p>
                <div class="t-center">
                    <p>In Charge:</p>
                    <p>(SEE INSTRUCTION ON BACK)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-one-half">
            <div class="top-left-text">
                <h4>CHRD - 001 - 0</h4>
                <h4>(Civil Service Form No. 48)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center-text">
                <h2>Daily Time Record</h2>
                <div class="line">-----o0o-----</div>
                <h4 class="name">Sample Name<h4>
                <h4 class="category">(Name)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center--info-text">
                <p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018<p>
                <p>Official hours for arrival &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Regular days Monday - Friday</p>
                <p>and departure 8 AM - 5 PM &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Saturdays None</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table-dtr">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Day</th>
                        <th colspan="2">A.M.</th>
                        <th colspan="2">P.M.</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Undertime</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <th>Departure</th>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <th>Departure</th> 
                        <th>Hours</th>
                        <th>Minutes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>16</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>17</th>
                        <td>07:35 AM</td>
                        <td>12:01 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>18</th>
                        <td>07:58 AM</td>
                        <td>12:07 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>19</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>20</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>21</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>22</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>23</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>24</th>
                        <td>08:05 AM</td>
                        <td>12:04 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>25</th>
                        <td>07:37 AM</td>
                        <td>12:05 PM</td>
                        <td>12:50 PM</td>
                        <td>05:03 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>26</th>
                        <td>07:50 AM</td>
                        <td>12:05 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:02 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>27</th>
                        <td>07:31 AM</td>
                        <td>12:00 PM</td>
                        <td>12:54 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>28</th>
                        <td>07:26 AM</td>
                        <td>12:06 PM</td>
                        <td>12:53 PM</td>
                        <td>05:05 PM</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>29</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>30</th>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {
                            ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 20px;">Total</th>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="text-center--info-text t-bottom">
                    <p> I certify on my honor that the above is a true and correct report of the hours of work performed, record of which was made daily at the time of arrival and departure from office.</p>
                </div>
                <p class="underline">___________________________________________</p>
                <p>VERIFIED as to the prescribed office hours:</p>
                <p class="underline">___________________________________________</p>
                <div class="t-center">
                    <p>In Charge:</p>
                    <p>(SEE INSTRUCTION ON BACK)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this
`<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018<p>`
To
`<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Please close all the tag you open. This must be require to use HTML2PDF library.

As per your code i got you started `<h4>` tag for `Sample Name` but not closed that tag please close that tag instead of new `<h4>` tag.

For Example:
Replace the following

```
<h4 class="name">Sample Name<h4>
```

To

```
<h4 class="name">Sample Name</h4>
```

You need to change this code at two places. Because this is available at two places.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the followings (same errors twice) :

```
<h4 class="name">Sample Name<h4> (l.11)
<h4 class="name">Sample Name</h4> (closing tag)

<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018<p> (l.15)              
<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018</p> (closing tag)

<h4 class="name">Sample Name<h4> (l.207)
<h4 class="name">Sample Name</h4> (closing tag)

<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018<p> (l.211)
<p>For the month of September 16 - September 30, 2018</p> (closing tag)
```

Tip : you can use an XML validation tool online to quickly find thoses ([example here](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)) but you will have to remove first all &nbsp; and php tags first.